# Book where teens travel to other worlds through a strange, moving cave

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I remember reading this book when I was around 14 (12-13 years ago). I think it was targeted to audiences of this age. I read it in French, but I expect it was originally published in English.

In this book, a boy and a girl found in the basement of one of their relatives the entry to a strange cave. The entry was circular and led to a lot of roughly spherical spaces all connected by similar entries. The material of the walls was strange, clearly not stone, and moist. While exploring this cave system, they noticed it was moving, and the passages were changing diameters. At some point they could not go back to the entrance, but randomly following passages they found a way out and emerged to a different, fantasy world.

The book is split into three or four parts, possibly these were initially published separately as a series of books. In each part they visit a different world in this way, and are able to come back afterwards. I don't remember what the worlds were or what adventures they live therein.

I believe the final revelation was that

> the moving cave was actually the brain of their relative, which expanded after some sort of experiment (maybe connecting it to a computer) and led to the worlds described in the books he used to read/write.

Comment: hm. have you tried anything from here?
https://www.nypl.org/blog/2017/11/22/finding-book-forgotten-title?page=3

Comment: Yes now, with no success.